# Please STOP requiring Google profile info, and switch to the other endpoint!

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, login, data-explorer, privacy

I know this change already took place some months ago, but I wanted to write about this now. Here's the situation:

- When I click on [image: log In page]
- I login on my Gmail account and get :[image: Google profile dialog][image]And I don’t have a public Google profile requiring me to create one *(asking age; address; sex; favorite color…)*[image]but in my case, if I click on<kbd>Accept</kbd> then I'm forced to upgrade to a Google profile because of the new Stack Exchange OpenId login behaviour *(which mean fulfilling street address; birthday; phone number; favourite colour…)*.
- If click on<kbd>Annuler</kbd>*(cancel)* I get :[image: the openid login fails]

I created a Gmail account in the early beginning, I only had to fill in the password, name, and email address. I also find unfair that others providers don't have to provide this information while it is required for Google.
I can understand this for things like Facebook... But, not every ***Google account*** is a ***Google profile***...

Also, let's be clear:

- No, **I will never upgrade, the same way I would never create a social media profile** *(I really dislike the bboard effect of the concept)*.
- **Do not try to convince me it's Google**, because the message states the contrary and it perfectly work if I login using those other ways :[image: stackexchange.com login page][image: meta.stackexchange.com login page]

### **Update:**

Ok, you are not using OpenId but Google+ Sign in *(which is not really OAuth 2.0)*. [According to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#sign-in), there are two endpoints, and using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login instead of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile prompt users to upgrade to a Google+ profile even if you only require an email address.
***Anyway*** Google clearly states it : ["Your app can either prompt those users to create a Google+ profile or not..."](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#sign-in), which means that Google requires you to upgrade to a Google profile only if requested.
I reported [it](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=1146) to Google, but I already guess they’ll say it’s not on their end too.

Comment: Stack Exchange didn't change their behavior with logging in via OpenID - Google did. *They* want you to upgrade your account, and are making it more difficult for you to do things if you don't.

Comment: @animuson : No, I only get this, with Stack Exchange,  other openid clients web site only ask my e-mail address *(which was SE doing until recently)*. And the translation of the main message on the second picture is : `Stack Exchange require:` `print your Google's profile informations` **which clearly state it's SE which is doing this**. And even if they would force users to upgrade one day, then they might get sued one more time in the country *(or they would have stopped asking for age; postal address; situation...)*. Even if 150,000€ is still *fine* for them, they should try to avoid this.

Comment: All Stack Exchange attempts to get is your email address, and afaik Google automatically includes some other stuff with that as well (which caused [this other question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234365/why-do-you-need-to-know-who-i-know-on-google)). Google translates that line to "display the basic information of your profile" - which is *exactly* what Stack Exchange has always requested. So... nothing has changed on their end.

Comment: @AnnaLear : did your really read the the last point in my question? Or the the `status-bydesign` is really here to confirm you changed you policy with Google for marketing purposes while still allowing some other providers to not require those informations?

Comment: @user2284570 See my answer.

Comment: @user2284570 I don't know why you rollbacked my edit. It is pretty annoying to scroll down half the page just to get to the answer. I didn't remove any content - just made it easier and less annoying for other users to read.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ : You need to understand that the images existing for the text they contains and they need to stay readable.

Comment: And you can't read the smaller images!? OK...

Comment: due to lower res yes.

Comment: Why don't you just add Stack Exchange OpenID then?

Comment: @ShadowWizard : If you know know how to add an Openɪᴅ to an existing account…

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers.

Answer (score 30):

It is absolutely Google's fault for [deprecating their OpenID 2.0 provider](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration) in favour of their OAuth 2.0/OpenID Connect provider backed by Google+. Considering how much more annoying OAuth 2.0 is to set up I feel this was a huge mistake, but they were the ones who made it.

Stack Exchange only requests the scopes `profile` and `email`, which [should not prompt you to upgrade to Google+](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#sign-in) like the `plus.login` scope would. It's unclear if that's specifically what you're saying is happening in your case, but if it is it sounds like Google is misrepresenting those scopes and that's something that would have to be brought up with them.

Note that your workaround of putting in the Google OpenID 2.0 endpoint manually will stop working as of April 2015, when that service is finally taken offline by Google.

Comment: Ok, So your're saying clicking on the icon doesn't invoke openid, but use a different method called OAuth?

Comment: Yes. It used to use OpenID, but Google is forcing everyone to switch to OAuth. This isn't *supposed* to impact you as a user, but I don't have a basic Google account to test to make sure how true this is.

Comment: Sure, just [follow the help center instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials).

Comment: You didn't really migrated to *OAuth 2.0* as *OAuth* is deprecated too *(albeit there's no plan for bringing it offline)*... You switched to Google+ Sign. They are instructions for migrating from [OAuth to Google+ Sign in](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#oauth2login).They also state :"[Sign-In provides support for all users, even if they have not yet created a Google+ profile. Your app can either prompt those users to create a Google+ profile (by using /auth/plus.login scope) or not (by using the *profile* scope)](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#sign-in)".

Comment: "Google+ Sign In" is just OAuth 2.0 with some extra things that Stack Exchange does not request. The "early version" of Google's OAuth 2.0 provider is what was deprecated, by the way.

Answer (score 16):

We can't use Google's OpenID endpoint anymore (even until  April) because we regularly launch new sites and Google only keeps the endpoint alive for existing domains.

I just tested this with a Google sign-in without a G+ profile and I can't reproduce what you're seeing. We already use the `profile` scope as you so emphatically suggest, and there is no requirement on our end for someone to have a Google+ profile associated with their Google account.

Comment: The same thing is happening again for Data Explorer :(.

Comment: @user2284570 I don't follow. Google no longer supports OpenID. It's not a bug on our end.

Comment: Yes, I recognize I can’t use the workaround of my question that time. But I guess if I ask Google they I guess they will say it’s not their end to.